# Where will my git branch stay when merge into remote master

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I'm working with some guys on a bitbucket repo.

We have a instruction that merges to master are done only through PR's.

I have a branch in my local repo, which i derive from a commit in my local master. That commit is not yet in the remote master.

If i push my branch to the remote and i request a PR into master.

Which commit will it be merged to? or it is just moved to the tip of remote master?

**Let me add this**

```
Local repo 
A <--- B <--- C

Remote repo
A <--- B <--- C
```

But we cannot push to master branch

So, I make a change to my local git master branch as this

```
A <--- B <--- C <--- D
```

I know i shouldn't have made that change and so, i'll probably have to check a new branch like

```
git checkout -b master-to-merge
```

And push that branch to be merged into remote master.

But my question is:

Assuming I have a branch like so

```
A <--- B <--- C <--- D 
                      \
                       \
                         E <--- F <--- G
```

I name the branch; feature-branch. If I push that feature branch to the remote repo to be merged into master. Since commit D is not in that repo, which commit will be the parent of the my feature-branch?

Comment: If you have pushed your branch, `D` is in the repo.  It is a necessary part of the history of your branch.  Just because `origin/master` hasn't been updated to `D` does not mean that `D` isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - based on your edit to your question, it appears you are specifically looking for phrasing I didn't use.  I didn't use it for a reason (it would be inaccurate language).  Here is why:

A branch does not have a parent commit.  A branch is a ref - i.e. a pointer to a single commit, not a collection of commits.  Other commits might be reachable from a branch (by parent pointers), but that's all the relationship there is.  Looking at an existing set of commits, you cannot tell where a branch was created.  Based on commit topology and typical usage patterns, you can guess; but whether your guess is right or wrong has no consequence.

So while your question is *trying* to be very precise, in terms of git concepts it is actually very imprecise; which is why I won't try to translate my answer into those terms.  This answer is precisely what the result will look like if you execute the PR; no more, no less.

---

Ok, so your current situation is

```
A --- B <--(origin/master)
       \
        C <--(master)
         \
          D --- E <--(branch)
```

You push `branch`, then you have

```
A --- B <--(origin/master)
       \
        C <--(master)
         \
          D --- E <--(branch)(origin/branch)
```

Note that unless you push `master`, neither the server nor any other clone is aware that you have `master` at `C`.  From their perspective, then, it appears that `C` is part of `branch`.

```
(coworker's repo)

A --- B <--(master)
       \
        C -- D --- E <--(branch)
```

Whether you *should* push `master` depends on your team practices.  If master is meant to be updated by PR, then I would assume not.  (I would also suggest that, in that case, you shouldn't really *have* a local change "on master".)

So I would expect the PR to resolve like this:

```
A --- B ------------ M <--(origin/master)
       \            /
        C -- D --- E <--(origin/branch)
```

Back in your local, after a fetch you would see

```
A --- B ---------------- M <--(origin/master)
       \                /
        C <--(master)  /
         \            /
          D -------- E <--(branch)(origin/branch)
```

which at first glance seems a little messy, but actually you can just fast-forward your local `master` to `origin/master` (in fact I believe that's what a `pull` would do by default), giving you

```
A --- B ------------ M <--(master)(origin/master)
       \            /
        C -- D --- E <--(branch)(origin/branch)
```

And now everyone agrees that `C` is just like another commit at the beginning of `branch`.  The merge parent is `B`, and the merge brings in `C` through `E`.

Comment: btw, I refer to `C` as appearing to be part of `master` with reservation, bc I believe people make too much of the idea that a commit is "on a branch", "part of a branch", whatever. That's not really a thing in git.  By convention, the final topology you get here would suggest that `C` was made as part of `branch` and that its changes contribute to the purpose of `branch`.  If that would be misleading, then another option would be to create a new branch at `C`, push/submit a PR for that, then after that's resolved you would address the original `branch`. But that has complications as well...

Comment: I've edited my question with similar diagrams for you to understand

Comment: @Subomi.js : And... what? Your question, after the edit, is the same as before. Is there some part of the answer you don't understand?

Comment: Wow, you have a very sound understanding of git. I actually did not read the answer at first, because i felt my question had nothing to do with a co-workers repo .. But now i understand better. 

The major thing is a branch is simply a commit and the commit will reference its parent so i thinking i've moved master forward, doesn't matter, to the remote C is part of branch .. So, nothing should really be done on master. 

thanks!!

Comment: Please do well to upvote the question. I guess its a good question in understanding git internals.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply push it to remote branch.

If you will create PR after merge on master PR will contain only your new commit. If you will create PR before merge on master PR should contain both commits.

I've tested it a bit:

some changes in repo

```
git add -a
git commit -m "master commit"
git checkout -b test-branch
```

some changes in repo

```
git add -a
git commit -m "commit on branch"
git push origin test-branch
```

PR:

[image]

and then:

```
git checkout master
git push
```

PR:

[image]